# How many groups of seven can be chosen to work on the project assuming two team members refuse to work together on the project?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A team has 13 members. Suppose two team members refuse to work together on project. How man groups of seven can be chosen to work on the project ?

I can not understand the solution.

$$ {11 \choose 6} + {11 \choose 6} + {11 \choose 7} $$

Comment: Reading quickly, I thought the first sentence of this was leading to a soft-question about classroom ethics/etiquitte (I didn't see "together"). 

I clicked in to see if you were one of the guys ratting out my laziness. :-)

Comment: @jaska Hahaha I guess I have to change the title.

Comment: It can also be solved by exclusion (all possible teams minus the teams that have both of the problematic members).

Answer (score 3):

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_{13}$ the members of the team, suppose that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are the two persons that refuse to work together. Then, let's to count how many ways to form groups there exist.

- If $X_1$ is in the group, then we must choose $6$ elements from the set of $11$ members $\{X_3,\ldots,X_{13}\}$. There are $\color{red}{{11 \choose 6}}$ ways to do this.
- If $X_2$ is in the group, we can use the same reasoning as above, giving us $\color{red}{{11 \choose 6}}$ groups.
- Finally, if $X_1$ and $X_2$ aren't in the group we have $\color{red}{{11 \choose 7}}$ different groups.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that the difficult people are Alicia and Beti.

We can choose Alicia to be on the project  committee, but not Beti. So we need to choose $6$ people from the remaining $11$ to join Alicia on the committee. This can be done in $\binom{11}{6}$ ways.

Or else we can choose Beti but not Alicia. This can also be done in $\binom{11}{6}$ ways.

Or else we can leave out both Alicia and Beti, in which case we need to choose $7$ people from the remaining $11$. This can be done in $\binom{11}{7}$ ways.

Answer (score 2):

Since two members refuse to work together, you have 11 other people on the project totally willing to work together.

For each one participating on the project, you have $11\choose6$ ways to form a team, since we are choosing 6 more people from the remaining 11. Thus -- "11 choose 6". There's two ways to do this, so we have to count both.

For neither of them participating, it's not an issue to *not* pick one of them, so we have $11\choose7$. Since we are excluding both from the start, we are choosing a team of 7 from a group of 11: that is, "11 choose 7".

Sum these three to get the answer.

BTW -- this is equivalent to ${13}\choose{7}$ $-$ $11\choose5$. Does that help you visualize it better?